# Is the order that Azure AD applies group claims to a ClaimsPrincipal reliable?

Tags: azure, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory

I have an application with multiple departmental levels. A user is a member of an AD group which represents a department. This group is then a member of another group representing a parent department, and so on through a number of levels.

I need to know this entire chain of transitive group memberships, but I also need to know which group the user is a direct (intransitive) member of.

Using the `groupMembershipClaims` property of the json manifest (as described in detail [here](http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/)) I get group claims on my authenticated ClaimsPrincipal without an additional call to the Graph API:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups : {guid-a}
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups : {guid-b}
...
```

So far, in all our tests, the first group `{guid-a}` is always the intrasitive one that my user is a direct member of, and subsequent groups are always in ascending order.

My question: is this order reliable? And if not, is there any other way without making a call to the Graph API that I can identify which group among many my user is a direct member of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **memberOf** property of a user to get only groups the user is a direct member of.  Here is a screen capture from the latest [Azure AD Graph REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations).

[image]

As for the order of the claims, I would advise against writing any code that depended on the claims being in a particular order.

Comment: Rick - thanks for the detailed response. I was already aware I could do this with the graph API.  "I would advise against writing any code that depended on the claims being in a particular order." - is that advice based on any concrete knowledge, or just an informed hunch?

Comment: Rick is right, you should NOT take a dependency on this order. It is merely a side-effect of AAD's back-end directory service and is not guaranteed to hold true moving forward. Only take a dependency if Microsoft has officially documented this. (This is based on concrete knowledge.)

Comment: @JcFx I just realized you said "without" using the Graph API.  Sorry about that. :)  Phillippe already responded about the dependency risk.  No special knowledge there other than experience.  Unless it's specifically documented assume it can change.

Comment: Thanks, both.That's what we had assumed (hence the question), but sometimes these things are just accidentally undocumented.